# Storing dates in mongodb with javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

Whilst experimenting with mongodb and javascript on the MEAN stack. I came across an issue when it came to dealing with the dates, so I am interested in hearing how others have tackled this kind of scenario.

Lets say I have three dates I want to store in mongodb, a "date of birth", an "account creation" date and "last visit" date.

- "**date of birth**" is self explanatory. This date should always be the same when presented to the user.
- "**account creation**" keeps the date/timestamp when an account was created. The user never sees this as it is for internal application usage.
- "**last visit**" shows the user the date/timestamp when they last used the application.

Now If I save all of these dates as normal Javascript date objects in mongodb, they are saved as UTC. The following then ensues:

1. "**date of birth**" is no longer correct if presented to the user as it was recalculated to UTC.
2. "**account creation**" is ok since its being used internally as long as its consitently UTC.
3. "**last visit**" is no longer correct if presented to the user as it was recalculated to UTC.

So faced with the dilemna of trying to avoid storing dates as strings but at the same time not willing to battle timezone complexities. What would be the best compromise to deal with this scenario in terms capturing, storing and then presenting the dates??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All date creation is not equal. An example:

What you likely did:

```
new Date("2014/01/01")
ISODate("2014-01-01T13:00:00Z")
```

And that factored the timezone difference into the date generated.

What you want to do:

```
new Date("2014-01-02")
ISODate("2014-01-02T00:00:00Z")
```

Which is exactly in UTC format.

So make sure you record such things as a UTC format when you create them.

Comment: new Date("yyyy-MM-DD") did want I wanted as it stops the recalculation of UTC since the original date is defaulted to be the UTC timezone not the local timezone. However I could not figure out how to get the current timestamp defaulted to UTC. e.g. new Date() would generate the time and default to the local timezone and then recalculate it to UTC. Is the a similar function that would just generate the current timestamp which is defaulted to UTC?